# How to properly escape in windows command shell - even the asterisk?

Tags: windows, command-line, escape-characters, parameters

By following good (though sometimes conflicting) advice such as
[Quotes, Escape Characters, Delimiters - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) or
[Escape character – Wikipedia, section 2.6 Windows_Command_Prompt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#Windows_Command_Prompt) or even
[The Windows NT Command Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//cc723564(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), I solved the problem of escaping to about 99%, but I am still struggling with the last bit. My uses case is specifying the password-arguments for decrypting or encrypting pdf files as command line parameters to `qpdf.exe`, so special chars are to be expected and welcome. If possible, I'd like to be able to use more or less *all* printable characters, with SPACE (U+0020) as only whitespace character.

There is no additional level of indirection such as piping the arguments between commands or invoking a batch file; all I need to produce is the "direct" command for the windows command line.

This is how far I got so far:

- Contrary to what is mentioned in the SS64.com link above, `COMMA` (U+002C), `SEMICOLON` (U+003B), and `EQUAL SIGN` (U+003D) pose no problem (for my use case at least)
- Just putting everything in `QUOTATION MARKS` (U+0022) while doubling preexisting  `QUOTATION MARKS` (U+0022), does not work properly as it leaves problems at leat with the `PERCENT SIGN` (U+0025).
- Also caret-escaping alone does not cover everything. One needs to mix the methods

So this is how I proceed so far:

1. Double quote any `QUOTATION MARK` only "locally", i.e., replace any U+0022 with U+0022 U+0022 U+0022 U+0022
2. Quote any `SPACE` only "locally", i.e., replace U+0020 with U+0022 U+0020 U+0022
3. Caret-escape the caret itself, i.e., replace U+005E with U+005E U+005E
4. Caret escape the remaining special characters (as listed in the linked articles), i.e., for `x` in `LESS-THAN SIGN` (U+003C), `GREATER-THAN SIGN` (U+003E), `AMPERSAND` (U+0026), `VERTICAL LINE` (U+007C), `LEFT PARENTHESIS` (U+0028), `RIGHT PARENTHESIS` (U+0029), replace any occurrence of `x` with U+005E `x`.
5. In addition, it seems to be necessary to caret escape the `PERCENT SIGN`, i.e, replace every  U+0025 with U+005E U+0025

Thus to specify a password such as **`Hello %TEMP%>"&abc`**, I would end up with

> C:\path\to\qpdf.exe --encrypt Hello" "^%TEMP^%^>""""^&abc someownerpassword 256 -- input.pdf output.pdf

This works fine, i.e., the password I need to enter in the password dialog window when opening output.pdf is indeed **`Hello %TEMP%>"&abc`**

There is but one (so far) evil character that defies all my attempts to escape it: the `ASTERISK` (U+0042)! No quoting, doubling, caret-escaping (or other escaping characters I tried at random) works for it -- it will always try to "glob". In some cases one may be lucky if no files match the glob, but I definitely need to ask a ...

**Question.** How would I escape a desired password such as **`*.*`** (U+0042 U+002E U+0042) and prevent it from globbing?

Comment: If at all possible, I'd suggest using another command shell, e.g. PowerShell. It will make your life much less miserable ;-)

Comment: Strange - for my Windows 10 PC when I type `someapp.exe "*.*"` as command line in CMD.EXE, the app is launched with one argument: `*.*`, whereas `someapp.exe *.*` uses the glob, converting to many arguments. Perhaps there is some `SETLOCAL` setting which affects this.